# Python pandas merge data by sorting and filling data by distance

Tags: python, pandas

I am able to to create a bunch of loops to resolve this problem to group them by family but I think that this problem could be possible resolved a lot faster by using pandas. 
I need to merge both data frame and interpolate the distance by family where the distance is .5~1 max. Any help would be appreciated.

```
print Df1

   family  distance   
0   A        2.18    
1   A        3.31  
3   B        4.31 
4   A        7.21     

print Df2
    family.1  distance.1    
1    B        4. 
2    A        3.05   
3    A        11.03

Desired output df3
   family  distance  family.1    distance.1
0   A        2.18     
1   A        3.31      A          3.05
3   B        4.31      B          4.2
4   A        7.21  
5                      A          11.03
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that need to be sorted by distance

Comment: I'm confused on the merging logic. Since you don'y have an ID, but have duplicate values in 'Family', how do you merge them? Are you saying `if 1 <= distance1 - distance <= .5` and Family is the same then merge?

Comment: The merge it's by the closest distance with the same family, let me know if that its more clear. Basically it needs to be an approximate of the closest distance per family